# Enviar peticion POST a API PHP desde Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente codigo en Angualar:

```
export class ApiAuthService{
   url: string = 'http://localhost:80/APIVENTAS/index.php/login/ingresar' ;
   private usuarioSubject!: BehaviorSubject<Usuario>;
   public usuario: Observable<Usuario>;
   public get usuarioData():Usuario{

     return this.usuarioSubject.value;
   
   }
   constructor(private router:Router,private http : HttpClient){
        this.usuarioSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Usuario>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario')!));
        this.usuario = this.usuarioSubject.asObservable();
   }
   login(login : Login):Observable<Response>{
       return this.http.post<Response>(this.url, login,httpOption).pipe(map(res=>{
   console.log(res);
         if(res.exito == 1){

            const usuario:Usuario = res.data;
            localStorage.setItem('usuario',JSON.stringify(usuario));
            this.usuarioSubject.next(usuario);
         }
         return res;
       }));
  
   }
   logout(){
    
     localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
     window.location.reload();

       }
}
```

como veran es un servicio para loguearse.

Por otro lado el modelo de "res" del servicio de angular es:

```
export interface Response {
    exito: number;
    mensaje: string;
    data: any;
}
```

Pero la verdad no se que puede estar fallando. Obtengo:
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'exito')**
Como que "res" es null.

Comment: En este tipo de problemas no debes mezclar ambas tecnologías en la misma pregunta. Si el problema es en Angular en lugar de agregar el código de la API en PHP solo agrega el JSON que devuelve. Y coloca bien las etiquetas, si el problema es en Angular la etiqueta debe ser `angular` no `php`.

Comment: Ok, ahi edite la pregunta..Devuelve null el console.log(res);

Comment: Usa las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador y revisa la petición que se está enviando, revisa si los datos que se están enviando son correctos y qué está retornando la Api. Si los datos enviados son correctos y la Api devuelve null, entonces te pasas a revisar la Api. Así vas depurando en orden cada parte del sistema.

Comment: La api si retorna genera el array donde esta "exito" pero me falta devolverlo. Voy a ver como lo planteo y de ultima edito la pregunta

Comment: Si el sistema es multiusuario: el token del lado del servidor lo puedo guardar en una variable de sesion($_SESSION) o debe ser en la base de datos? Esta ultima opcion parece mas lenta

Comment: Si es una arquitectura REST el token se guarda en el cliente y se envía en cada petición.

Comment: Que opciones le estas pasando en el objeto `httpOption`?

Comment: Se guarda en el cliente pero tengo que validarlo comparándolo en el servidor? O solo con el tiempo de expiración?

Comment: @Caruso en teoría, tu token debería ser válido contra el seed que le paste (llave privada). Esto se realiza en cada petición. Como estas trabajando con una api rest, el servidor no guarda el estado del cliente (con excepciones) así que se crean middlewares (pasos intermedios) para validar el token antes de continuar sirviendo peticiones. Una de estas validaciones es el tiempo de expiración,  y el tercero suele ser cuando tu, programáticamente das de baja un token. (cerrar sesión, cambio de contraseña, etc.) Esto comúnmente se realiza registrando los tokens validos en la BD.